# asp.net web services initialization

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service (asmx) to return a list of icons urls as json . Where should I put initialization of the list of all the icons ? I want the list be initialized once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply load the list into a static variable in your service class.  The static initialization should only happen the first time the class is loaded by IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this question: [C# How to initialize WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328666/c-how-to-initialize-webservice)